# NLog save entries to database(postgresql),

Tags: nlog, asp.net-core-logging

Search on many post, all compared to almost identical but somehow its doesn't send entries to DB.

logging file works, but database not..

nlog.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true"
      internalLogLevel="Trace"
      internalLogFile="c:logs\internallog.txt">
  <extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore" />
  </extensions>
  <targets>
    <target name="database" xsi:type="Database"
            dbProvider="Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection, Npgsql"
            connectionString="User ID=postgres;Password=123456;Host=localhost;Port=5432;Database=Telepati_Dev;">
      <!--//Pooling=true;-->
      <commandText>
        insert into systemlogs(log_date,log_level,log_logger,log_message,log_machine_name, log_user_name, log_call_site, log_thread, log_exception, log_stacktrace) values(@time_stamp, @level, @logger, @message,@machinename, @user_name, @call_site, @threadid, @log_exception, @stacktrace);
      </commandText>
      <parameter name="@time_stamp" layout="${longdate}" />
      <parameter name="@level" layout="${level}" />
      <parameter name="@logger" layout="${logger}" />
      <parameter name="@message" layout="${message}" />
      <parameter name="@machinename" layout="${machinename}" />
      <parameter name="@user_name" layout="${windows-identity:domain=true}" />
      <parameter name="@call_site" layout="${callsite:filename=true}" />
      <parameter name="@threadid" layout="${threadid}" />
      <parameter name="@log_exception" layout="${exception}" />
      <parameter name="@stacktrace" layout="${stacktrace}" />
    </target>
    <target xsi:type="File" name="ownFile-web" fileName="c:\logs\ApplicationLogs-${shortdate}.log"
            layout="${longdate}|${event-properties:item=EventId_Id}|${uppercase:${level}}|${logger}|${message} CorrelationId=${aspnet-item:variable=CorrelationId} ${exception:format=tostring}|url: ${aspnet-request-url}|controller: ${aspnet-MVC-Controller}, action: ${aspnet-mvc-action}" />
  </targets>
  <rules>
    <!--All logs, including from Microsoft-->
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="allfile" />

    <!--Skip non-critical Microsoft logs and so log only own logs-->
    <logger name="Microsoft.*" maxlevel="Info" final="true" />
    <!-- BlackHole without writeTo -->
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="ownFile-web" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Api project gets dbcontext from data layer so does Npgsql reference

here is API nugget refs;

[image]

and data layer packages;

[image]

here are some contents of "internallog.txt";

```
2020-05-31 02:07:32.3212 Trace Opening c:\logs\ApplicationLogs-2020-05-31.log with allowFileSharedWriting=False
2020-05-31 02:07:32.3503 Trace Opening c:\logs\ApplicationLogs-2020-05-31.log with allowFileSharedWriting=False
2020-05-31 02:07:32.3642 Trace Opening c:\logs\ApplicationLogs-2020-05-31.log with allowFileSharedWriting=False
2020-05-31 02:07:32.3774 Trace Opening c:\logs\ApplicationLogs-2020-05-31.log with allowFileSharedWriting=False
2020-05-31 02:07:32.3934 Trace Opening c:\logs\ApplicationLogs-2020-05-31.log with allowFileSharedWriting=False
2020-05-31 02:07:32.4091 Trace Opening c:\logs\ApplicationLogs-2020-05-31.log with allowFileSharedWriting=False
2020-05-31 02:07:32.4245 Trace Opening c:\logs\ApplicationLogs-2020-05-31.log with allowFileSharedWriting=False
2020-05-31 02:07:32.4403 Trace Opening c:\logs\ApplicationLogs-2020-05-31.log with allowFileSharedWriting=False
2020-05-31 02:07:32.4551 Trace Opening c:\logs\ApplicationLogs-2020-05-31.log with allowFileSharedWriting=False
2020-05-31 02:07:32.4771 Debug Targets for Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command by level:
2020-05-31 02:07:32.4771 Debug Trace =>
2020-05-31 02:07:32.4771 Debug Debug =>
2020-05-31 02:07:32.4947 Debug Info =>
2020-05-31 02:07:32.4947 Debug Warn => ownFile-web
2020-05-31 02:07:32.4947 Debug Error => ownFile-web
2020-05-31 02:07:32.5119 Debug Fatal => ownFile-web
2020-05-31 02:07:32.5119 Debug Targets for Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query by level:
2020-05-31 02:07:32.5119 Debug Trace =>
2020-05-31 02:07:32.5279 Debug Debug =>
2020-05-31 02:07:32.5279 Debug Info =>
2020-05-31 02:07:32.5279 Debug Warn => ownFile-web
2020-05-31 02:07:32.5428 Debug Error => ownFile-web
2020-05-31 02:07:32.5428 Debug Fatal => ownFile-web
2020-05-31 02:07:32.5428 Debug Targets for Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Transaction by level:
2020-05-31 02:07:32.5594 Debug Trace =>
2020-05-31 02:07:32.5594 Debug Debug =>
2020-05-31 02:07:32.5704 Debug Info =>
2020-05-31 02:07:32.5704 Debug Warn => ownFile-web
2020-05-31 02:07:32.5704 Debug Error => ownFile-web
2020-05-31 02:07:32.5856 Debug Fatal => ownFile-web
2020-05-31 02:07:32.5856 Debug Targets for Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection by level:
2020-05-31 02:07:32.5856 Debug Trace =>
2020-05-31 02:07:32.6033 Debug Debug =>
2020-05-31 02:07:32.6033 Debug Info =>
2020-05-31 02:07:32.6033 Debug Warn => ownFile-web
2020-05-31 02:07:32.6186 Debug Error => ownFile-web
2020-05-31 02:07:32.6186 Debug Fatal => ownFile-web
2020-05-31 02:07:32.6403 Debug Targets for Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update by level:
```

whats missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a rule that writes to the database target in your config.

E.g. Replace

```
<logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="ownFile-web" />
```

With

```
<logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="ownFile-web, database" />
```